# Can Vim's keyword completion be limited to only same filetype?

Tags: vim

I find Vim's keyword completion very useful when I only have files of the same filetype open. But as soon as I start editing more than one filetype, it becomes much less useful. If I'm editing a Python project and then open my vimrc in another tab, keyword completion from inside a Python file will now include keywords from my vimrc. Without disabling the options for complete to look in other buffers, is it possible to have keyword completion work only with buffers of the same filetype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good idea. I'm a huge fan of the Vim insert-mode completion, and have written a library that makes it easy to implement custom completions: [CompleteHelper](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3914).

With a little enhancement to that library (which I've just implemented in version 1.30), it allows to limit the completion candidates to certain buffers. With this, I've implemented your suggestion as the [SameFiletypeComplete plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4242). Try it out; I hope it's useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `<C-n>`/`<C-p>`, right?

The value of `set complete` determines the completion sources. The default value includes the content of other buffers and windows in the completion list.

See `:help 'complete'` for a list of options. This will probably solve your problem:

```
:set complete=.,t,i
```

Alternatively, you could use other completion shortcuts like `<C-x><C-n>`, `<C-x><C-p>` or `<C-x><C-o>`, depending on what you want to complete. See `:help ins-completion`.

Comment: Removing w,b,u from complete is doing the opposite of what I asked. I am using supertab, which defaults to using c-p, which is normal keyword completion. So I guess what I want is a user-completion function that does the same as keyword completion, but restricts it to buffers of the same filetype.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part of your question. But you forgot to mention that you were using a third party plugin which introduces many variables in the equation and reduces the chances of answering correctly. Isn't it possible to setup Supertab so that it does what you want? What about `<C-x><C-p>`?

Comment: <C-x><C-p> only searches for keywords in the current file. I want it to do what <C-p> does- also look for keywords in other open files- but **only** if those other files are of the same filetype. It looks like the only way to do this is to re-implement <C-p> logic in vimscript as a completefunc, with the one additional conditional on filetype.